# Installing a software (Papyrus 5.0) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse, make, configure

I was trying to install papyrus on Ubuntu, but I am a newbie to Ubuntu and don't exactly know how to install it. I have downloaded a tar.gz (of papyrus) file. After extraction I have the following files in the folder:

|| artifacts.xml || eclipseproduct || icon.xpm || **papyrus** || plugins
||  **configuration** || features || p2 || papyrus.ini || readme ||

According to conventional installation I was supposed to run "./configure" before "make" and "make install", but I don't have any configure option.
I tried "./papyrus" and "./papyrus.ini".
In configuration folder. I tried all sorts of commands such as "./config","./configure","./configuration" but none was fruitful.
files in Configuration directory are:

|| org.eclipse.core.runtime ||               org.eclipse.osgi
||                 org.eclipse.equinox.app  ||               org.eclipse.update
|| 1613242018864.log  || org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator
|| **config.ini**     ||   org.eclipse.equinox.source ||

Here I also tried "./config.ini" it showed some sort of log but it didn't lead to "make" option.
I can use the application directly by running the main executable file, but it doesn't install on the system yet.
*The read-me folder was also not helpful :(.
Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is Papyrus? Is there a website? Did you forget to post the link? As is, there is not much we can help you with.

Comment: @mikewhatever https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/download.html is the link of the software. Its basically a tool to convert UMLs to Code (Java in my case).
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from a commenter, Papyrus is an Eclipse-based application for drawing UML diagrams.

After you install the papyrus tar.gz file, the "papyrus" file is the executable. You would have seen the hint for that if you had showed the "ls -lt" output in that directory.